# How to Change Date Format from "3 Aug 2020" to "03.08.2020" in Google Data Studio?

Tags: datetime, looker-studio

I'm using Google Data Studio with Google Sheets as a Data Source. In the Data Source, I have a Date column (German regional settings: `03.08.2020`). But the Google Data Studio table displays the value as `3 Aug 2020` (so it does interpret it as a date, but the format is wrong). I found no setting to change that, I've also tried using a calculated field with `TODATE` function, but I don't know the syntax to convert `Aug` to `08` (`Aug` without a dot).
And all the rows without a value set, display "null" (as text). Is this a bug?

**EDIT**: this is what it looks like after I've converted the source field to Text (setting data type to date or to text renders the same output in Google Data Studio):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`FORMAT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9730334) function can be used to change the **Date Format** from the default (varies based on Google Account language settings) `Aug 3, 2020` to `03.08.2020` (where `Date` represents the name of the current Date field):

### 0) Type: Date

At the Data Source set the **Semantic Type** of the current Date field back to `Date`

### 1) [`FORMAT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9730334)

```
FORMAT_DATETIME("%d.%m.%Y", Date)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5599c2d2-0a59-47cb-81d4-fe0b75843064) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Comment: The problem is now that the field is no longer an actual date, so sorting will not work correctly for anything that relies on this. (%d.%m.%Y does not work with lphabetic sorting)

Comment: @SilasHansen: Yes, it's a text field, however, the sort field could be set to the original date field